# Standard Deviation in R

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the standard deviation from scratch in R (I do know R has a build-in function for that), but I'm not getting the correct results, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
My.SD<-function(X) {
  M<-(sum(X)/length(X))
  my.var<-sum((X-M)^2)
  StanDev<-sqrt(my.var/length(X))
  print(StanDev)
}
```

Comment: You need to show us your output(s) and tell us what you were expecting.

Comment: `sd`, is extremely well tested. If you're not matching expectations it could be related to your input data, like errant NA data (`sd` has a `na.rm=TRUE` parameter)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you might need to use `(length(X)-1)` rather than `length(x)`, i.e.,

```
My.SD<-function(X) {
  M<-(sum(X)/length(X))
  my.var<-sum((X-M)^2)
  StanDev<-sqrt(my.var/(length(X)-1))
  print(StanDev)
}
```

since here it should be sample standard deviation.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! :D

Comment: - Can you explain why the length-1?

Comment: @user12541161 since it is sample standard deviation, not the standard deviation. There are different things. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation

Comment: That's how standard deviation from a sample is calculated. Without the adjustment the estimate tends to be too small.